# HttpClient Get works when Fiddler is on and fails with 403 when fiddler is not running

Tags: httpclient, fiddler

I have seen many posts but none of the solution is helping me. I have a simple get to one of the Amazon new webservices. The client is HttpClient.

When fiddler is on it passes and gets me result. When fiddler is not running it fails. Since it was not failing when fiddler was on, i installed another tool "Http Debugger" to see the failure and i could not make any difference in both the request (The pass and the failure). Bothe of them are given below

Failure Capture:

```
GET /sellers/v1/marketplaceParticipations HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
x-amz-access-token: Atza|IwEBIN3hOVtNi1xM47txtHcqXi5A3C960AypB7pkWYCxEo7lNiL9EFR-1b_EoD6PQ8lzAXgM4zujF0OBv0NS7sYQ9bWqPMDhHFt8kgvdmlmk3==jrinknrO6PYlZgmFLRGn1Hzmvgldmnj4973bjkfnbkldlcvld vc0BmuqKHUreonrWQxFO49u0yoIiNHVzSxHP0Wo4nWKW5pdd5Fj73gYxnZQQeYF5EAy8lKDCLtndTnJCdlrv5Kk8JK8iFD_H7h3FF5H4gNyTx3uIHxMaU8OkLz_IigsCTNQHwljnubhQlR9aK0J6lRbb0QfOQ4BAT_e1GOKDkShu-U5OdchdF5qNUkKU
user-agent: MSolution/1.0.0.0
X-Amz-Date: 20201201T224620Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIA5SU6JNBJKDAQB76813QI6V/20201201/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date, Signature=71dd12ee0eaf33cd142dwr242424e91cb5c4bfd6fd4f46d929d
Host: sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The error is Forbiden (Just this)

The success capture is (Fiddler running):

```
GET /sellers/v1/marketplaceParticipations HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
x-amz-access-token: Atza|IwEBIMfdZDDaca8HrDGIPft-HQs3Vzi75I4Bk9iNKfsHTkfwsfsfcsvcsaP86DqKkoZE37TiDr3XvmD_vdvavcUE9TzdXhf2jjuULL04keBHI_XYrnTnhXaCPE0gUAc8HvIiW7OXSERz_3RlS9R-nu2lTo_jqzaz0mbUaa-evavaVAVLauh2Ue7Io8pE1tThRTcqM60igPcrBViAUptTAsq-IL5ZT7hOfbNJTJ31GeN8e8IzjkWfe9n4l7B799VM1bJnC-D_alZ2J0HHj4cBNjd3RzAEvavav3fGWkW5iH2_MZ3IyaxYnslvSzNH4h8tvay87OywkkxVUKIn
user-agent: MSolution/1.0.0.0
X-Amz-Date: 20201201T224820Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAYWBDAQ7XYIPQI6V/20201201/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date, Signature=7e4db1c114219546848eaffnvclknslnlcvs63c9e0af50edc3cdbe7231c9b
Host: sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
```

I have used:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                  (senderSP, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Not sure what is causing this but has anyone seen this ?

The same call through "RestSharp" works, but i donot wnat to use rest sharp.

- Shankar

Comment: I also tried adding the Connection in the Signed headers as well, but that did not work

Comment: HTTP 403 means that you are not allowed to use. In your scenario I would assume that the site you are trying to connect to is using a anti-ddos system like cloudflare which identifies the type of client you are using based on the TLS handshake.